# Undefined method 'install!'

Tags: cocoapods

I'm running CocoaPods `0.39.0`, and I'm getting the following error when I run `pod install`:

```
[!] Invalid `Podfile` file: undefined method `install!' for #<Pod::Podfile:0x007fc3e993c510>. 
Updating CocoaPods might fix the issue.
```

This is the line in my `Podfile` that is causing the error:

```
install! 'cocoapods', :deterministic_uuids => false
```

I tried running `gem install cocoapods` to update everything, just to make sure that wasn't the problem. It didn't help.

`install!` is listed as a valid command in the Cocoapods documentation. Is it not available in `0.39.0`? Is the solution to update to the current beta?

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing the CocoaPods documentation further, it does appear that the `install!` command is only available in the beta version. After running `sudo gem install cocoapods --pre` and then re-installing the pod, everything worked.